# How to build protocol driven SwiftUI View structure?

Tags: swiftui

I've defined two protocols

```
protocol AxisInstanceProtocol {
    var name:String {get set}
}

protocol StyledAxisProtocol {
    associatedtype  AxisInstance: AxisInstanceProtocol
    var axisInstances: [AxisInstance] {get set}
}
```

And I try to build SwiftUI views structure.

```
struct StyledAxesView<StyledAxis: StyledAxisProtocol>: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var environment: ContentManger
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach ((0..<environment.axes.count), id: \.self) { axisIndex in
                StyledAxisView(styledAxis: self.$environment.axes[axisIndex])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I put `ContentManagerClass` inside `StyledViewAxis` to siplify `<StyledAxis:StyledAxisProtocol>`. I think It's OK. It's much easier to define it as `StyleAxesView<MyStyledAxis>.ContentManger` than comapare types in all subviews later.

```
extension StyledAxesView {
    class ContentManger: ObservableObject {
        @Published var axes: [StyledAxis] = []
    }
}
```

On the bottom I have View for `AxisInstance`:

```
struct InstanceView<AxisInstance: AxisInstanceProtocol>: View {
    
    @Binding var instance: AxisInstance
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(instance.name)")
        // Will be much more complicated, editing many parameters of the `instance`
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to make ForEach loop to pass `instances` into separte views and make them @Binded (?) to update whole `[StyledAxis]` array.

```
struct StyledAxisView<StyledAxis: StyledAxisProtocol> : View {
    @Binding var styledAxis: StyledAxis
    
    var body : some View {
        
        VStack {
            ForEach ($styledAxis.axisInstances, id: \.self) { instance in
                 InstanceView(instance: instance)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this version I have an error `Cannot convert value of type 'InstanceView<AxisInstance>' to closure result type '_'`. I tried many differnt approaches, no one of them compiled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is possible approach (modified only part, tested with Xcode 12)

```
struct StyledAxisView<StyledAxis: StyledAxisProtocol> : View {
    @Binding var styledAxis: StyledAxis

    var body : some View {

        VStack {
            ForEach (styledAxis.axisInstances.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                 InstanceView(instance: self.$styledAxis.axisInstances[index])
            }
        }
    }
}
```